# Wordpress overwrites UNC

Tags: filters, customization

I am using wordpress multisite.  When editing a post, adding a link to a file in UNC format, and clicking save, wordpress is stripping out the drive letter and colon before the data hits the database.  'N:/file.pdf' is being saved as '/file.pdf'.

This is only true for users who are not network super admins.

Does anyone know what might be causing this behavior, and how I can change it?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369147/linking-a-unc-network-drive-on-an-html-page This may be more trouble than you expect.

Comment: There is a custom hook on the display side that converts the UNC into a usable link, so display side is no problem. I'm focused on how I can get what is put into the editor to make it through to the database.

Comment: I just posted a couple of possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You could attempt to [alter the allowed protocols](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/functions.php#L3737).

```
function wp_allowed_protocols_unc_wpse_100080($protocols) {
  return $protocols + array('file');
}
add_filter('kses_allowed_protocols','wp_allowed_protocols_unc_wpse_100080');
```

And add links of the form `file://///path/to/file.txt`-- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369147/linking-a-unc-network-drive-on-an-html-page

I do not know if that will work. That need for five slashes could be an issue.

You could also create a shortcode.

```
function unc_link_wpse_100078($atts,$content) {
  return '<a href="file://///'.$content.'">'.$content.'</a>';
}
add_shortcode('unc','unc_link_wpse_100078');
```

Add your links to post with `[unc]path/to/file.txt[/unc]`

That is a very simple version but it should survive the post content filters. My guess is that that option will be by far the least hassle.

Comment: Thank you for the help - this got me on the right track to understand what was going on.  In my case, adding the expected drive mappings to allowed_protocols fixed my problem.

I still don't understand why this wasn't happening for network super admins - I guess the allowed protocol filter isn't being applied to their edits?

Comment: Good. I wasn't sure if that would work.

Comment: I'd have to look into it but yes, it is very possible that super-admins have fewer filters applied, or different ones.

Comment: In multisite, super-admins have the unfiltered_html capability, which allows them to do lots more types of things in posts than normal users do.